# How to retrieve and display an image as json response in phonegap android application?

Tags: android, json, cordova

This is my json response :-

```
{"Value":[{"Image":"http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/688_dummyadd.jpg","TargetUrl":"http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.html","Remark":"Sucess"}]}
```

And this is my .js code:-

```
function showAds(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async : false,
        success : function(msg) {
            respo = msg.Value;          
            $("#adddiv img").remove();
            $.each(respo, function(index, value) {
                if(value.Image != null) {
                    image = value.Image;
                    targetUrl = value.TargetUrl;
                    $respo =  '<img src="'+ image +'" width="266" height="56">';
                    $('#adddiv').append($respo);            
                }                           
            });
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
            alert('Error Occoured');
        }
    });}
```

but i am unable to display the banner on the screen.How can i do this? Do i need some change in my approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html
in `adddiv`

```
<img id="id_img" src="'+ image +'" width="266" height="56" src="../img_loading.gif" style="display: none;">
```

in JS

```
.....

....

 if(value.Image != null) {
    image = value.Image;
    var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    $("#id_img").show();
    $("#id_img").attr("src", image);
}
img.src = image;           
                          }
```

Comment: its working Geet ...thanx for ur response...will you plz tell me if on click event on image i have to open a webpage in mobile browser from the application...how could i do that ....??? ....However really thnx for ur rsponse...

Comment: you need to put image url on `onClick` event with function.like `onclick=OpenMyPage(url)`. in function u can call `window.location = url`.